# Using rails_admin with rails_api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, actionview, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I originally posted this as [an issue on rails_api GitHub](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2617), but am now posting it here due to inactivity.

I'm trying to use `rails_admin` with a Rails 5 API application. I included extra ActionController modules up to the point that I can either have a functioning rails_admin panel or working API requests. The issue seems to be that rails_admin depends on `ActionView::Layouts`, which after included causes issues for API requests.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '>= 5.0.0.beta3', '< 5.1'
...
gem 'rack-pjax', github: 'afcapel/rack-pjax'
gem 'remotipart', github: 'mshibuya/remotipart'
gem 'kaminari', github: 'amatsuda/kaminari', branch: '0-17-stable'
gem 'rails_admin', github: 'sferik/rails_admin'
```

I configured my application to use `ActionDispatch::Flash`:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
  end
end
```

[I configured extra modules for Rails API](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api#choosing-controller-modules), ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Knock::Authenticatable
  include Pundit

  # RailsAdmin support
  include AbstractController::Helpers
  include ActionController::Flash
  include ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods
  include ActionView::Layouts
end
```

With these changes the Rails Admin dashboard seems to run fine. However, when I'm trying to access the JSON resources in my application, the following error is thrown:

```
Error:
BookingsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template bookings/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/richard/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails_admin-355dc80f8a20/app/views"
```

The test code (also tried adding `format: :json`):

```
class BookingsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test 'should get index' do
    get :index

    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

This is the controller code:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @bookings = find_bookings
    render json: @bookings, include: ['customer', 'client'], meta: meta
  end
end
```

This only happens after I include the `ActionView::Layouts` module in the top level `ActionController::API` class to support Rails Admin.

Comment: What is in your `BookingsControllerTest`? I think it would help to know, since that's where the problem is ...

Comment: Have you tried using [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) like rails-api recommends?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I were you, I try isolate API and RailsAdmin controllers. I think this must work:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Knock::Authenticatable
  include Pundit
end

class RailsAdminCustomController < ApplicationController
  # RailsAdmin support
  include AbstractController::Helpers
  include ActionController::Flash
  include ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods
  include ActionView::Layouts
end
```

In `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  # other config stuff ...
  config.parent_controller = '::RailsAdminCustomController'
end
```

Just check the `RailsAdmin::ApplicationController` [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/controllers/rails_admin/application_controller.rb#L13), and the config settings [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Base-configuration).

Answer (score 3):

As of `v1.0.0` (released September 2016), Rails Admin now supports Rails 5 API-mode straight out-of-the-box. The gem itself injects the missing middleware to render its views and there is no extra configuration required.

Links:

- [Using Rails Admin with Rails 5 API application](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/how-to-use-rails-admin-with-a-rails-5-api-application.html?utm_source=stackoverflow)
- [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100---2016-09-19)

Comment: This is true! Meanwhile I've resorted to updating rails_admin and removing the custom solution mentioned above.

Comment: It worked till `1.1.0` if i'm not wrong; I get `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):` now with Rails 5.1.2 and rails_admin 1.2

Comment: Yes that's correct. There's an open issue with this that I describe [here](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/how-to-use-rails-admin-with-a-rails-5-api-application.html#comment-3399871556)

Comment: What about Devise and it's sign_in view?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a json view file in this location bookings/index.json.jbuilder
And inside this file something like

bookings/index.json.jbuilder

```
json.name @bookings.name
json.date @bookings.date
```

This is another template missing

> application/index

but really don't know you app completely. So maybe that's the application layout you implemented using ActionView::Layouts. In that case is asking you to implement a layout page file in the location application/index.

NOTE: Those two file inside the views folder.