# ruby can't verify csrf token authenticity api rails admin import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I'm building a ruby API using rails admin (which is working) and rails admin import which has this problem:

> Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.

Tried to deactivate it with

```
module Api::V1
  class ApiController < ApplicationController     
     skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
...
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
      skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

But the result was the same error. Any ideas?

Thank you

P.S:
Also getting this when I put the code above(as it apears not to be implemented)

```
"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"
"exception":"# ArgumentError: Before process_action callback :verify_authenticity_token has not been defined"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you setup rails_admin?

Did you try using different controllers for both API and RailsAdmin, adding the needed includes in the later? Namely including `ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection` as described in [Using rails_admin with rails_api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840247/using-rails-admin-with-rails-api)?